# What other repository systems have cvs's -D (date) option?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I recently stumbled upon a cool feature in CVS where you can name revisions by date, e.g.:

```
# List changes made between the latest revision 24 hours ago and now
cvs diff -D "1 day ago"
```

Do any other repository systems (e.g. Git, SVN, Bazaar, Mercurial, etc.) have an option like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial has a wide range of date formats: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#date-formats, though maybe not "1 day ago".

[This subversion bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=343142) indicates that Subversion can't do it natively, but does offer a tip on using `date` to do it:

> (2) Whilst Subversion doesn't understand -r "{3 days ago}", date can
>   help out there too: -r "{`date -Is -d '3 days ago'`}".

Answer (score 2):

Subversion has a similar feature. For example:

```
svn diff -r {2010-07-31}
```

The syntax is explained in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates

Answer (score 0):

*(answering my own question)*

git log supports dates for filtering before or after given times.  Example:

```
git log --after='july 17 2010' --before='july 31 2010'
```

Here's a shell script that makes it a little easier to list ranges of commits, but it also uses a terser format than git log's default:

```
#!/bin/sh
# git-changes

FORMAT='%cd%x09%h%n%x09%s%n'
CMD="git log --format=format:$FORMAT"

case $# in
    0 )
        $CMD ;;
    1 )
        $CMD "--after=`date -d "$1"`" ;;
    2 )
        $CMD "--after=`date -d "$1"`" --before="`date -d "$2"`";;
esac
```

Note:  I wrapped the date arguments with the date command, since git treats `'July 17'` as a few hours off from `'July 17 2010'` for some reason.

Usage:

```
git-changes                  # Same as git log, but more terse
git-changes 'yesterday'      # List all commits from 24 hours ago to now
git-changes 'jul 17' 'aug 1' # List all commits after July 17 at midnight
                             #              and before August 1 at midnight.
```

Sample output of `git-changes 'jul 17' 'aug 1'`:

```
Sat Jul 31 23:43:47 2010 -0400  86a6727
        * Moved libcurl into project directory as static lib.

Sat Jul 31 20:04:24 2010 -0400  3a4eb10
        * Added configuration file support.

Sat Jul 31 17:44:53 2010 -0400  aa2046b
        * Fixed truncation bug in bit parser.

Sat Jul 17 00:10:57 2010 -0400  99e8124
        * Added support for more bits.
```

Now, to see all changes introduced by commit 99e8124, type `git show 99e8124`.  To see all changes since revision 99e8124 (not including that commit itself), type `git diff 99e8124`.